# Error during create coroutine function with co_await with Task<> as return type

Tags: c++, coroutine

It's my defined Task type: https://godbolt.org/z/qYfbbb

I want to test this code by using them in such example:

```
auto intProducer = [](int value) ->tinycoro::Task<int>{
    co_return value;
};
tinycoro::Task<> test2(){
    tinycoro::Task<int> prod = intProducer(123);
    std::cout << "before " << std::endl;

    int res = co_await prod;
    std::cout << "finished " << std::endl;
}
```

But I have such error:

```
Error: cannot convert 'coroutine_handle<TaskPromise<void>>' to 'coroutine_handle<TaskPromise<int>>'
  200 |     int res = co_await prod;
      |                        ^~~~
```

And I don't understand, what the reason - there is similar example in cppcoro library https://github.com/lewissbaker/cppcoro#taskt

(I'm compiling it with gcc10 with -fcoroutines)

Comment: `await_suspend` is passed a handle to the coroutine that is being suspended. In your case, it is a handle to the `test2()` coroutine, which is a `coroutine_handle<TaskPromise<void>>` because `test2()`'s promise is `TaskPromise<void>`. `prod` is a `Task<.int>`, and its `await_suspend` says that it accepts a `coroutine_handle<TaskPromise<int>>`, which is not compatible with `coroutine_handle<TaskPromise<void>>`. Usually, `await_suspend` doesn't care what type of coroutine is await on it, so it just takes a `coroutine_handle<>`, which is the base class for all coroutine handles.

Comment: @Raymond Chan Ok, now I understand, thanks.
But how it works, in example from cppcoro? There is count_lines coroutine (with cppcoro::task<int> return), which is co_awaited in usage_example (and there is a cppcoro::task<>)?

Comment: Oh, I read again your last sentense, and after change CoroHandle to std::coroutine_handle<> now compiles, thanks!

Comment: You can see that [cppcoro's `task::await_suspend`](https://github.com/lewissbaker/cppcoro/blob/a87e97fe5b6091ca9f6de4637736b8e0d8b109cf/include/cppcoro/task.hpp#L314) uses `std::coroutine_handle<>`.